# notebook turned off while upgrading

Tags: upgrade

ok, so yesterday I was upgrading my ubuntu to 13.10 and it already started the "getting new packages" when my note's battery got low and it turned off. when I turned it on, I noticed that software update settings were changed (they all have been turned off) and now when I am launching the software updater it starts its checking but in the the end saying that it is finished it doesn't give me the list of updates, it just gets frozen. so what can I do in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will upgrade/fix any packages that didn't get properly upgraded when you lost power:

```
sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install -f; sudo apt-get upgrade -y; sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -y
```

You may want to watch the output carefully to see if anything is broken. If so, `sudo apt-get purge <package-name>; sudo apt-get install <package-name>` will fix things.